# Autodesk Maya channelBox() function limitations

Tags: maya

I apologize in advance if this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow since is Maya Python specific. If it isn't I would appreciate any forum recommendation!

This year I started to learn properly python to use it as a way to create tools for Autodesk Maya (I'm an animator) and after some time I was thinking in the possibility to make it a side hustle for additional income. I wasn't looking for clients (since I'm still learning), but someone reached out to me to ask if I would be able to create a tool he wants to have, so I decided to give it a try but I told him that I wasn't sure if what he wanted to do was possible.

Essentially he wants to create a Channel Box that has the capability to change the colors of the attributes. When I heard it I thought it was very difficult to do and when I tried it I realized that it was kind of possible with the channel box function built-in function, but it was very limited for the client needs since he wants those colors being independent from one object from another (for example, two different NURBS curves, or two different geometries having different attribute colors in the channel box).

My second though was that it may be possible by building a channel box from scratch, and I wondered if with OpenMaya I would be able to do it, but by looking at it, it was too advanced for my current skill. Now I'm just wondering if what this client wants to do is even possible, but it requires a more experienced programmer, or if it's possible even with an beginner-intermediate level.

Thank you!!!

Comment: you should check this https://github.com/robertjoosten/maya-channel-box-plus

Comment: Thank you! I checked it and it helps a lot. It looks like it's possible but it requires more experience and knowledge than I currently have. But I already know what to tell to the client. Thanks again!